# how do i extract data from <br> tags from a html page using Beautiful soup-Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

i am trying a python requests to extract data using Beautifulsoup from br tag but i am unable to achieve, if any one guide me on how to extract it that will be great, Thanks in advance below is the html:

```
<div class="value"><p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Operating System</strong></span><br><br><strong>Operating System</strong><br>Windows 10 Home<br>Acer recommends Windows 10 Pro for business<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Processor</strong></span><br><br><strong>Processor Manufacturer</strong><br>Intel®<br><br><strong>Processor Type</strong><br>Core™ i5<br><br><strong>Processor Model</strong><br>i5-1135G7<br><br><strong>Processor Speed</strong><br>2.40 GHz<br><br><strong>Processor Core</strong><br>Quad-core (4 Core™)<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Display &amp; Graphics</strong></span><br><br><strong>Graphics Controller Manufacturer</strong><br>Intel®<br><br><strong>Graphics Controller Model</strong><br>Iris Xe Graphics<br><br><strong>Graphics Memory Accessibility</strong><br>Shared<br><br><strong>Screen Size</strong><br>39.6 cm (15.6")<br><br><strong>Display Screen Type</strong><br>LCD<br><br><strong>Display Screen Technology</strong><br>ComfyView (Matte)<br><br><strong>Screen Mode</strong><br>Full HD<br><br><strong>Backlight Technology</strong><br>LED<br><br><strong>Screen Resolution</strong><br>1920 x 1080<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Memory</strong></span><br><br><strong>Standard Memory</strong><br>8 GB<br><br><strong>Memory Technology</strong><br>DDR4 SDRAM<br><br><strong>Number of Total Memory Slots</strong><br>2<br><br><strong>Memory Card Reader</strong><br>Yes<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Storage</strong></span><br><br><strong>Total Hard Drive Capacity</strong><br>1 TB<br><br><strong>Hard Drive Interface</strong><br>Serial ATA<br><br><strong>Optical Drive Type</strong><br>No<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Network &amp; Communication</strong></span><br><br><strong>Wireless LAN Standard</strong><br>IEEE 802.11 a/g/n/ac/ax<br><br><strong>Ethernet Technology</strong><br>Gigabit Ethernet<br><br><strong>Bluetooth Standard</strong><br>Bluetooth 5.0<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Built-in Devices</strong></span><br><br><strong>Microphone</strong><br>Yes<br><br><strong>Finger Print Reader</strong><br>Yes<br><br><strong>Number of Speakers</strong><br>2<br><br><strong>Sound Mode</strong><br>Stereo<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Interfaces/Ports</strong></span><br><br><strong>HDMI</strong><br>Yes<br><br><strong>Number of HDMI Outputs</strong><br>1<br><br><strong>VGA</strong><br>Yes<br><br><strong>Number of USB 3.2 Gen 1 Type-A Ports</strong><br>3<br><br><strong>Number of USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C Ports</strong><br>1<br><br><strong>Total Number of USB Ports</strong><br>4<br><br><strong>USB Type-C</strong><br>Yes<br><br><strong>USB Type-C Detail</strong><br>USB Type-C port: USB 3.2 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps), DisplayPort over USB-C, USB charging 5 V; 3 A, DC-in port 20 V; 60 W<br><br><strong>Network (RJ-45)</strong><br>Yes<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Software</strong></span><br><br><strong>Operating System</strong><br>Windows 10 Home<br>Acer recommends Windows 10 Pro for business<br><br><strong>Operating System Architecture</strong><br>64-bit<br><br><strong>Upgradable Windows OS</strong><br>Yes<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Input Devices</strong></span><br><br><strong>Pointing Device Type</strong><br>TouchPad<br><br><strong>Keyboard</strong><br>Yes<br><br><strong>Keyboard Backlight</strong><br>Yes<br><br><strong>TouchPad Features</strong><br>Multi-touch Gesture<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Battery Information</strong></span><br><br><strong>Number of Cells</strong><br>3-cell<br><br><strong>Battery Chemistry</strong><br>Lithium Ion (Li-Ion)<br><br><strong>Maximum Battery Run Time</strong><br>12 Hour<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Power Description</strong></span><br><br><strong>Maximum Power Supply Wattage</strong><br>45 W<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Physical Characteristics</strong></span><br><br><strong>Height</strong><br>19.90 mm<br><br><strong>Width</strong><br>363 mm<br><br><strong>Depth</strong><br>255 mm<br><br><strong>Weight (Approximate)</strong><br>1.80 kg<br><br><strong>Colour</strong><br>Shale Black<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Miscellaneous</strong></span><br><br><strong>Package Contents</strong><br>TravelMate P2 TMP215-53-589A Notebook<br>Lithium Ion Battery<br>AC Adapter<br><br><strong>Security Features</strong><br>SmartCard reader slot<br>Kensington Lock Slot<br>Discrete Trusted Platform Module (TPM) Solution<br><br><strong>BIOS Passwords :</strong><br>User<br>Supervisor<br>Acer ProShield Security Manager Including:<br>Data Protection: File Encryption &amp; Decryption, Personal Secure Drive<br>Data Removal: File Shredder<br>Security Alert: Invalid Access Alert, Security Report<br><br><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Warranty</strong></span><br><br><strong>Warranty</strong><br>Standard Warranty</p></div>
```

[image]

What i want is I have created two blank list
head = []
value = []

-append Operating System, Processor Manufacturer in head.(Highlight tags without an underline)
and
-append its value-> Windows 10 Home Acer recommends Windows 10 Pro for business , Intel® in value

and final_list should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got you html above into a soup, try this:

```
head = [strong.text for strong in soup.select('strong')][:4]
value = [nx.next.strip() for nx in soup.select('br') if len(nx.next.strip())>0 ][:4]
print(head)
print(value)
```

The output, based on the html in your question should be your expected output.

Comment: Hi Jack, Thankyou for your response, i really appreciate it. Regarding the solution for head , - What i want is the text should come from pure <strong> tag. What is happening here is that the text is coming from all strong tags, including the strong tag which is under span.
and for Value i am getting an error of NoneType object is not callable

Comment: @MandarRaut The problem is probably that your actual html is different from the sample xml in the question. The answer does work with the sample, though.

Comment: Well i am not sure why its happening because i have copied entire html as it is,
the html comes from [link](https://www.pcshopper.co.za/acer-travelmate-p2-nx-vpvea-002.html)  you can click on Detailed Specification tab to find the table. if you could check this that would be great. Thanks